# Can't assign specific type as an argument to a generic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to set an interface where I can pass arguments without specifying its type.

```
// Wrapper.tsx
interface Props extends MenuProps, ChakraProps {
  handleTagClick: <T>(args?: T) => void
}

export const Wrapper: FC<Props> = ({ handleTagClick }): JSX.Element => {
  return(
    <Button 
       {...(
          handleTagClick && { 
            onClick: () => handleTagClick({ ...dummyQuestion, type }) })
       }
    />
  )
}
```

Then I call that component where the error comes:

```
export const Container = () => {

  const { addNewThing } = useMyHook()

  // The error comes from this line
  return <Wrapper handleTagClick={addNewThing} />
}
```

The error:

```
Type '(question: VariableConfig) => void' is not assignable to type '<T>(args?: T | undefined) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'question' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to type 'VariableConfig'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'VariableConfig'.
Wrapper.tsx(10, 3): The expected type comes from property 'handleTagClick' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Partial<Props> & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is saying that the generic function type accepts `undefined` as the param type, but the function you're trying to pass to it doesn't, which is incompatible.

Comment: Possible quick fix: `<T>(args: T) => void` since you're never calling it with undefined (without any params).

Comment: @EmileBergeron same error: ```Type '(question: VariableConfig) => void' is not assignable to type '<T>(args: T) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'question' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'VariableConfig'.```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/lWYzrw) so that others can demonstrate your issue (and only your issue) for themselves.  This allows others to get to work on the solution instead of first needing to work on re-creating the problem. My strong suspicion here is that you need `Props` to be generic and not `handleTagClick`, but without an example I can play with I wouldn't want to hazard a guess at an actual answer.

Comment: I was thinking about it and then realised that there's really no direct solution since it would make no sense. In your case, it looks like you know the type (or part of the type) already in the generic wrapper since `handleTagClick({ ...dummyQuestion, type })` passes a param explicitly, you could probably come up with some general type to extend from. Otherwise, if it's really optional and unknown in advance, a generic makes no sense and it should probably be `handleTagClick: (args?: any) => void`.

Answer (score -3):

You designed the component so that it is accepting the function with the argument of type `unknown` among the props. That means, inside the component, it supposed that this function could be provided with such an argument. When you pass the function accepting an argument of only `VariableConfig` type it might result in an error if it would have an argument of another type (`unknown`). It is not expected. To fix that:

```
interface Props extends MenuProps, ChakraProps {
  handleTagClick: (args: VariableConfig) => void
}
```

---

UPD. Since my answer seems not complete I added more details in the explanation. I am breaking them into paragraphs.

1. First of all. TypeScript is essentially a framework allowing you to mountain type safety. That means it tracks all possible (as possible) states of all your variables and says if some of them are not safe. It is when a variable could be bound to a value of a type that is not allowed. You know it on the stage of compilation. But if you ignore it could result in a runtime error.
2. I don't know the business logic of your app to judge what you really need. But if you have a component that is accepting the function that in its turn is accepting an argument of type `unknown` and then you give the function that is accepting the constrain of `unknown` it is a dangerous situation. Imagine, the component inside its logic gives this function a value outside the constrain. This will mean the possible runtime error.
3. For me it says you have a flaw in the design of the component. What you need is to audit the logic inside your app.
4. The generic

```
interface Props extends MenuProps, ChakraProps {
  handleTagClick: <T>(args?: T) => void;
}
```

does not have a lot of sense. Actually, this is the same as to express

```
interface Props extends MenuProps, ChakraProps {
  handleTagClick: (args?: unknown) => void;
}
```

5. Possible solutions. You can turn off the job that TypeScript is doing. You can do it by this:

```
return <Wrapper handleTagClick={addNewThing as any} />;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoUSWOGATzCTgG84AxAYTgF85tcCRdDDLlKAOxhIomdEwCyScQFcACjjABnFtwlSZcuBwAWKANZQU6iFp17pstEwBqKKMBQAjADZIOEcUxgAHMWcjg+CAgALjgUcToKXQATJDRvNyY0AM14ACFlGBgA2M4AHmRsqGSy+LoAGjiEgD5milT0zLhs8Vy4ZU0keToACSizWIAKAEo4AF5msIiUZOSAOSQAdwAVY2BxYKmAR2UkXOASuFd3L19-QJDZhbgANwhgZKSKewMnOGtbEgAB5ScTJbSKFQAzSNEzmSzQpZwUxg3zbFDBDjeYBoCZwSZuYKaAD8sWU4jM4ggm3ET0Wbw+STEwOo8B6fQA6pYwIwoKUOGVoYs5vjWCjkmiMVicWYeNNYgApADKAA0AHQAUV8ICU8GezHC3Ry8GSyhAIDoAEVTucAvMdBQIuz4PRGPbyakguIkJ8xBEiDBlFBxPjDREygUigEwxEWGr4wbY0m4AFpbipnTkfEJUh0ZjsbjJqx42rTearTaYBdxI1XUxuNN6jGItxdEmAPTNQ3TL7MoGso29eD3GAofbSe0zeaLRODvqsFbrLa7fahXgigZDUbjGbff1IQPBuBlLkoHkT8WS-MyubMRcbHZ7A5xbR1Xid3tAA)

But in this case, you will come to uncertainty and TypeScrip is no longer going to help you.

6. Second solution. Write two different components. One with `handleTagClick` accepting arguments of all types and the second accepting only `VariableConfig`.

```
interface Props extends MenuProps, ChakraProps {
  handleTagClick: (args?: unknown) => void;
}

interface PropsVariableConfig extends MenuProps, ChakraProps {
  handleTagClick: (args: VariableConfig) => void;
}

export const Wrapper: FC<Props> = ({ handleTagClick }): JSX.Element => {

  return (
    <Button
      {...{
        onClick: () => handleTagClick({ ...dummyQuestion, type }),
      }}
    />
  );
};

export const WrapperVariableConfig: FC<PropsVariableConfig> = ({
  handleTagClick,
}): JSX.Element => {

  return (
    <Button
      {...{
        onClick: () => handleTagClick(dummyQuestion),
      }}
    />
  );
};

export const Container = () => {
  const { addNewThing } = useMyHook();

  return <WrapperVariableConfig handleTagClick={addNewThing} />;
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoUSWOGATzCTgG84AxAYTgF85tcCRdDDLlKAOxhIomdEwCyScQFcACjjABnFtwlSZcuBwAWKANZQU6iFp17pstEwBqKKMBQAjADZIOEcUxgAHMWcjg+CAgALjgUcToKXQATJDRvNyY0AM14ACFlGBgA2M4AHmRsqGSy+LoAGjiEgD5milT0zLhs8Vy4ZU0keToACSizWIAKAEo4AF5msIiUZOSAOSQAdwAVY2BxYKmAR2UkXOASuFd3L19-QJDZhbgANwhgZKSKewMnOGtbEgAB5ScTJbSKFQAzSNEzmSzQpZwUxg3zbFDBDjeYBoCZwSZuYKaAD8sWU4jM4ggm3ET0Wbw+STE+30jiY0OuHh8fgCQVCwNB4LgkLUGhhRlMFisYqRKOSaIxWJxeIJUCJsU5tx5D2CdNe70+5F05GB1HgPT6AHVLGBGFBShwytDFnN8aw5QrMdjcTxprEAFIAZQAGgA6ACivhASngz2Y4W6OXgyWUIBAdAAiqdzgF5joKBELfB6Iw8+TUkFxEhDQmiDBlFBxPiExEygUigEWxEWKHe-HuwO4AElbipnqPUh0V7lZNWL3Qym05nszALuJGiWmNxpvUuxFuLoBwB6ZoJ6ZfMSm6DmpNwa0oW3STXc+58h1OsXPu68kIut0JicpxHMxd23AMQwjKMY3mRZ+0TXpk1TdMszOVdc1dZheBQbQv21PlvgiOsGybSYuzbQpinEPcez7aiImHb0VXHeJ5UnRVGMmRdkJXNcd2og8uxPM8LxNIEzXgvp7hgFB9mkPMZhgpEixYOJVg2HY9gOHgy0GYYxggMwZgIuAiMbOAynvR8oFw18QmRFjPWAuZmBWdYtl2fZgl4E8LyAA)

7. The last thing you can do is to add a kinda type guard wrapper for function. It will filter arguments throwing an error when the argument is of an unsupported type.

```
declare const isVariableConfigGuard = (x: unknown): x is VariableConfig;

const wrapInVariableConfigGuard = (
  f: (question: VariableConfig) => void
): ((args?: unknown) => void) => (args?: unknown) => {
  if (isVariableConfigGuard(args)) {
    return f(args);
  }

  throw Error('An argument is of not supported type');
};

export const Container = () => {
  const { addNewThing } = useMyHook();

  return <Wrapper handleTagClick={wrapInVariableConfigGuard(addNewThing)} />;
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoUSWOGATzCTgG84AxAYTgF85tcCRdDDLlKAOxhIomdEwCyScQFcACjjABnFtwlSZcuBwAWKANZQU6iFp17pstEwBqKKMBQAjADZIOEcUxgAHMWcjg+CAgALjgUcToKXQATJDRvNyY0AM14ACFlGBgA2M4AHmRsqGSy+LoAGjiEgD5milT0zLhs8Vy4ZU0keToACSizWIAKAEo4AF5msIiUZOSAOSQAdwAVY2BxYKmAR2UkXOASuFd3L19-QJDZhbgANwhgZKSKewMnOGtbEgAB5ScTJbSKFQAzSNEzmSzQpZwUxg3zbFDBDjeYBoCZwSZuYKaAD8sWU4jM4ggm3ET0Wbw+STEwOo8B6fQA6pYwIwoKUOGVoYs5vjWCjkmiMVicWYeNNYgApADKAA0AHQAUV8ICU8GezHC3Ry8GSyhAIDoAEVTucAvMdBQIuz4PRGPbyakguIkJ8xBEiDBlFBxPjDREygUigEwxEWGr4wbY0m4AFpbipnTkfEJUh0ZjsbjJqx42rTearTaYBdxI1XUxuNN6jGItxdEmAPTNQ3TL5iZ1wYCaa4eHx+AJBYIAcWUbmS9smQLJFKpNPlcCBA+0w9uY4eoQWhrrEEw6-mcxF+AgngAVmkRHAAGQP08AQnPcBU3m8j+f+EwUXwAcQyBb5+02bkAElxG3Ud7gnadZ3nQ1MGOStq1iGC7nHR55npd5knINdJgJKAiVJfpl2pWlcNefDMxIsil0pKjM0TAcT0mQdMN3eCZ2qBjNGmWY2P9JBA2DPgBJ7Q1dEPYwcE2OANSgHAoEmfAAEEQ0JM1dU3FMTypeBNGUHloCkOc63waTuG+FlzKNXp4HuGAUH2aR51Yw1+1YFZ1i2XZ9lCXgRQGIZRnGGZvlE8SQzKLkUB5DzxUlfMZTmZhwMSqDuLgkIEP4vyNh2PYDmmXhO17IA)

But in this case, you need to have an error boundary on the upper level in your app. This pattern is to make the logic less transparent and more confusing.

Comment: This is not what I need because `handleTagClick` might accept another types as arguments, not only `VariableConfig `.

Comment: Let me expand my explanation.
1. First of all. TypeScript is essentially a framework allowing you to mountain type safety. That means it tracks all possible (as possible) states of all your variables and says if some of them are not safe. It is when a variable could be bound to a value of a type that is not allowed. You know it on the stage of compilation. But if you ignore it could result in a runtime error.

Comment: 2. I don't know the business logic of your app to judge what you really need. But if you have a component that is accepting the function that in its turn is accepting an argument of type `unknown` and then you give the function that is accepting the constrain of `unknown` it is dangerous situation. Imagine, the component inside its logic gives this function a value outside the constrain. This will mean the possible runtime error.

Comment: 3. For me it says you have a flaw in the design of the component. What you need is to audit the logic inside your app.

Comment: 4. The generic `interface Props extends MenuProps, ChakraProps {
  handleTagClick: <T>(args?: T) => void
}` does not have a lot of sense. Actualy this is the same as to express `interface Props extends MenuProps, ChakraProps {
  handleTagClick: (args?: unknown) => void
}`

Comment: 5. Possible solutions. You can turn off the work that TypeScript is doing. You can do it by this: `return <Wrapper handleTagClick={addNewThing as any} />`. But in this case, you will come to uncertainty and TypeScrip is going to help you no longer.

Comment: 6. Second solution. Write two different components. One with `handleTagClick` accepting arguments of all types and the second accepting only `VariableConfig`. `interface PropsVariableConfig extends MenuProps, ChakraProps {
  handleTagClick: (args: VariableConfig) => void;
}`, `export const WrapperVariableConfig: FC<PropsVariableConfig> = ({ handleTagClick }): JSX.Element => {

  return (
    <Button
      {...({
        onClick: () => handleTagClick(dummyQuestion as VariableConfig),
      })}
    />
  );
};`...

Comment: `export const Container = () => {
  const { addNewThing } = useMyHook();

  return <WrapperVariableConfig handleTagClick={addNewThing} />;
};` https://tsplay.dev/KwXaVN

Comment: 7. The last thing you can do is to add a kinda type guard wrapper for function. It will filter arguments throwing an error when the argument of unsupported typ. `const isVariableConfigGuard = (x: unknown): x is VariableConfig => {...};`, `const wrapInVariableConfigGuard = (
  f: (question: VariableConfig) => void
): ((args?: unknown) => void) => (args?: unknown) => {
  if (isVariableConfigGuard(args)) {
    return f(args);
  }

  throw Error('An argument of not supported type');
};`

Comment: `export const Container = () => {
  const { addNewThing } = useMyHook();

  return <Wrapper handleTagClick={wrapInVariableConfigGuard(addNewThing)} />;
};`. But in this case you need to have an error boundary on the upper level in your app. This pattern is to make the logic less transparent and more confusing. https://tsplay.dev/PmLKbN

Comment: For convenience, I am updating my original answer by adding these thoughts.